# WPF DataGrid - how to suspend UI updates from databind and do a bulk update later

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, updates, ui-thread

Having to do a lot of cell-by-cell changes in code on my source `DataTable`, I need a way to temporarily halt it sending data-binding updates to its bound `DataGrid`:

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a `DataTable` in code behind.

`DataGrid` has defined columns in XAML along with binding properties:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource str_Line}" Binding="{Binding Path=Pkey}" />
```

In code behind at load time I assign the data source (DataTable) to my grid:

```
myGrid.ItemsSource = myTable.DefaultView;
```

Now due to having to run a bunch of custom data formatting on the display data (mostly having to blank out some columns based on values of other columns, also some image switching) I am updating this source table manually - it's relatively small, always less than 20 rows. I am going row by row, cell by cell and determining whether or not this particular cell needs it's value hidden or displayed.

I don't want my UI thread getting a separate update event for each cell but I haven't found any way to switch binding.

Found the Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger property - but that still means a separate update for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Set your UpdateSourceTrigger to Explicit. You can get the binding expression you want to refresh and call UpdateTarget when you are ready.  See [BindingExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613455.aspx).

Comment: I can't find how to access that property on the bindings of columns either in code or in XAML.